Trouble updating Entity Framework
To give you some context: I am trying to workout how to make EF Core work and failing miserably I might add.
I am currently stuck on a problem that just I don't know why it isn't working out.
I just can't seem to understand it. I don't understand how EF Core creates the tables I just don't understand how does it reach to that point.
So the thing is right now there are cycles or multiple cascade paths on my database on the autogenerated one that is. That I do understand. I have messed up with my code a bunch to the point of removing like half of what I think is as much as I can remove of the [Required] attribute as well as signalize the data type as nullable.
What baffles me is that the exact same errors keeps popping as much as I make the values optional, of the one I think is the troublesome one, now another solution I found was just overriding and making everything ON DELETE NO ACTION via:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        // Change DeleteBehavior to Restrict to avoid cascade paths
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.NoAction;
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

Supposedly that's meant to hard override and make everything not do anything on delete, which I know its bad but at this point I just want to make this thing run at the very least, but yet nothing.
This is the error that pops up:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_HistorialActivo_Usuario_UsuarioID_Usuario' on table 'HistorialActivo' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

More info that the error message reveals:

Failed executing DbCommand (29ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [HistorialActivo] (
[ID_Historial] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[ID_Activo] int NOT NULL,
[ID_CambioTipo] int NOT NULL,
[ID_Usuario] int NULL,
[Fecha_Cambio] datetime2 NOT NULL,
[ActivoID_Activo] int NOT NULL,
[CambioTipoID_CambioTipo] int NOT NULL,
[UsuarioID_Usuario] int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_HistorialActivo] PRIMARY KEY ([ID_Historial]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_HistorialActivo_Activo_ActivoID_Activo] FOREIGN KEY ([ActivoID_Activo]) REFERENCES [Activo] ([ID_Activo]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_HistorialActivo_CambioTipo_CambioTipoID_CambioTipo] FOREIGN KEY ([CambioTipoID_CambioTipo]) REFERENCES [CambioTipo] ([ID_CambioTipo]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_HistorialActivo_Usuario_UsuarioID_Usuario] FOREIGN KEY ([UsuarioID_Usuario]) REFERENCES [Usuario] ([ID_Usuario]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

The troublesome entity (I think) is this:
public class HistorialActivo
{
        [Key]
        public int ID_Historial { get; set; }

        public int? ID_Activo { get; set; }
        public int? ID_CambioTipo { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Usuario { get; set; } 

        [Required]
        public DateTime Fecha_Cambio { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual Activo? Activo { get; set; }
        public virtual CambioTipo? CambioTipo { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario? Usuario { get; set; }
}

As I mentioned before I have tried making everything straight up nullable, making everything on cascade do nothing, even clearing up my migrations, making another DB, hell even for the fun of it I just used a different connection string. Yet I find myself with nothing.
Also If it means anything this is the full Database I was trying to create:
CREATE TABLE Procesadores 
(
    ID_Procesador INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Frecuencia DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Memorias 
(
    ID_Memoria INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Capacidad INT NOT NULL,
    Tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE DiscosDuros 
(
    ID_DiscoDuro INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Capacidad INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Monitores 
(
    ID_Monitor INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Tamaño DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    Resolucion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Impresoras  
(
    ID_Impresora INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Empresas 
(
    ID_Empresa INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre_Empresa VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NIT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Clientes 
(
    ID_Cliente INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Empresa INT,
    Nombre_Cliente VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255),
    Telefono VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Empresa) REFERENCES Empresas(ID_Empresa) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Usuarios  
(
    ID_Usuario INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Cliente INT,
    Nombre_Usuario VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255),
    Telefono VARCHAR(50),
    Estado VARCHAR(10) CHECK (Estado IN ('activo', 'despedido')) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Cliente) REFERENCES Clientes(ID_Cliente) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Tecnicos 
(
    ID_Tecnico INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre_Tecnico VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Telefono VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Activos  
(
    ID_Activo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Usuario INT NULL,
    Tipo_Activo VARCHAR(10) CHECK (Tipo_Activo IN ('portatil', 'escritorio')) NOT NULL,
    Marca VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ID_Procesador INT NULL,
    ID_Memoria INT NULL,
    ID_DiscoDuro INT NULL,
    Tarjeta_Video VARCHAR(100),
    Monitor INT NULL,
    Estado VARCHAR(10) CHECK (Estado IN ('activo', 'inactivo')) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Usuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(ID_Usuario) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Procesador) REFERENCES Procesadores(ID_Procesador) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Memoria) REFERENCES Memorias(ID_Memoria) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_DiscoDuro) REFERENCES DiscosDuros(ID_DiscoDuro) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Mantenimientos 
(
    ID_Mantenimiento INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Activo INT,
    ID_Tecnico INT,
    Fecha_Mantenimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    Tipo_Mantenimiento VARCHAR(15) CHECK (Tipo_Mantenimiento IN ('preventivo', 'correctivo')) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    Reporte BIT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Activo) REFERENCES Activos(ID_Activo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Tecnico) REFERENCES Tecnicos(ID_Tecnico)
);

CREATE TABLE CambioTipos 
(
    ID_CambioTipo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Tipo_Descripcion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE -- e.g., 'Cambio de Usuario', 'Mantenimiento'
);

CREATE TABLE HistorialActivos 
(
    ID_Historial INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Activo INT NOT NULL,
    ID_CambioTipo INT NOT NULL,
    ID_Usuario INT, -- The user involved in the change
    Fecha_Cambio DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Activo) REFERENCES Activos(ID_Activo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_CambioTipo) REFERENCES CambioTipos(ID_CambioTipo),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Usuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(ID_Usuario) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

Any feedback or guidance towards solving this problem or just learning EF Core and how it generates the Tables in general is highly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Fastest way out I would recommend? Run those SQL statements in a brand new DB, in SSMS.. Then check all the relationships on a db diagram.. The use the EFCore Power Tools VS extension to reverse engineer the database into an EF context. Then compare what it wrote with what you wrote. The context it wrote will Just Work (tm) and let you move on with life, and also probably inform as to what went wrong.. I'm a big fan of DB first to get up and running - maybe switch to code first later, but sometimes using EF is like trying to thread a needle when the thread is attached to the front of a bus

Oh, and have a real close think about what cascade actions you want in the sql before you run the script

Did you look at the other numerous questions on this exception "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" with entity frameworrk? It's pretty straightforward what it says and what to do about it.
